# JQuery enable clicking when div returns to normal state

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to disable clicking on other divs when the clicked div is active ?

I'm using **JQuery .toggle()** function.

**JQuery** for the the two left divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.move_box_left_up').toggle(function() {
        $(this).css({"z-index":"20"});
        $(this).animate({"height": "529px", "width": "460px"}, "slow");
        $(this).find('img').animate({"width": "460px"}, "slow");
    },function() {
        $(this).find('img').animate({"width": "220px"}, "slow");
        $(this).animate({"height": "163px", "width": "220px"}, "slow");
        setTimeout( function(){$('.move_box_left_up').css({"z-index":"10"});},500);
    })
});
```

**JQuery** for the the two right divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.move_box_right_up').toggle(function() {
        $(this).css({"z-index":"20"});
        $(this).animate({"height": "529px", "width": "460px", "left":"-=240px"},"slow");
        $(this).find('img').animate({"width": "460px"}, "slow");
    },function() {
        $(this).find('img').animate({"width": "220px"}, "slow");
        $(this).animate({"height": "163px", "width": "220px","left":"+=240px"}, "slow");
        setTimeout( function(){$('.move_box_right_up').css({"z-index":"10"});},500);
    })
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrX4y/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps having a conditional and setting a focus like attribute would be appropriate:

```
if ($('div[selected=selected]').length < 1) {
    $(this).attr("selected", "true");
```

Edit: updated code

http://jsfiddle.net/cjmwZ/1

Comment: After adding the animations and css into the conditionals it looks like that it's working. I see what you mean before... the right divs used to run away after a conbination of clicks.